# SQLite create a table for each point or store as string

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy, normalization

I need to store 3D points in a database (SQLite using SQLAlchemy). Each 3D point set would contain ~1000 points and I have up to hundreds of point sets. I have been using JSON to convert each of the point X, Y, Z coordinates to a large string then storing the 3 strings in a single table.

```
from db.base import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

class PointData(Base):
    ''' Raw point data, cannot store array in sqlite '''
    #JSON strings 
    x_data = Column(String(), nullable=True)
    y_data = Column(String(), nullable=True)
    z_data = Column(String(), nullable=True)
```

The other option would be to create a table for each point in the point set - and I would end up with ~1000 tables. Which is a better method for database overall size and performance - large single tables or many more small tables?

Comment: I would say: one table plus a proper index on the `point_set_id` column. One table is much easier to maintain (imagine you wanted to add a field `created_at` or `modified_by` to over thousand of tables). And performance should not be an issue with this size given you utilise indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your proposed solutions are not normalized.

Create two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE PointSet (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE Point (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    pointSetId INTEGER REFERENCES PointSet(id),
    x NUMERIC,
    y NUMERIC,
    z NUMERIC
)
```

For every point, insert a row into the `Point` table with `pointSetId` set to the ID of the set it belongs to. Query the Points table by filtering out rows where the `pointSetId` doesn't match.